# ¿De dónde viene la expresión "indirecta del padre Cobos", que es una verdad desnuda y no una "indirecta"?

Tags: etimología, modismos, españa, antónimos

En el DLE figura [**indirecto, ta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LPBzYJt) como

> 1. adj. Que no va rectamente a un fin, aunque se encamine a él.
>   2. f. Dicho o medio de que alguien se vale para no significar explícita o claramente algo, y darlo, sin embargo, a entender.

A continuación aparece la expresión

> **indirecta del padre Cobos**
>   1. f. Explícita y rotunda manifestación o declaración de aquello que se quería o se debía dar a entender embozada o indirectamente.

que es todo lo contrario de una indirecta (segunda acepción), es decir, una indirecta totalmente directa.

Figura ya en el Diccionario de la Lengua de 1734, pero sin el **padre**:

> **Indirecta de Cobos**
>   Expresión con que notamos al que claramente pide o dice las cosas juzgando que las disimula.

y es en la edición de 1803 cuando aparece como:

> **Indirecta del P. Cobos**
>   fam. El medio, o proposición con que claramente se pide alguna cosa, ó se dice a otro lo que le es desagradable.

He encontrado ejemplos de su uso reciente, por ejemplo [**aquí**](https://www.pagina12.com.ar/diario/elpais/subnotas/140735-45322-2010-02-21.html):

> ... la foto que aquí se reproduce, tomada durante una visita a Santa Fe, el 26 de mayo de 2009. Al pie dice “Gerardo Anadón, Gonzalo Costal, Cobos y Yo en la inauguración de la nueva planta de NOVA S.A., Cañada de Gómez, Santa Fe”. La foto es un ejemplo exacto de la expresión coloquial española “la indirecta del padre Cobos”...

Y entre las referencias más antiguas que he visto en la Hemeroteca Digital destaca la que corresponde a [El Español (Madrid. 1835). 1/10/1837, n.º 699, página 2](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003489624&page=2&search=indirecta%20padre%20Cobos&lang=es) (énfasis mío):

> El señor ministro dijo que yo había calificado el dictamen con desvergüenzas, porque dije que mas bien que hipocresía había **indirectas del padre Cobos**. Señores, yo no he usado la palabra desvergüenzas, y en cuatro años que tengo el honor de estar sentado en estos bancos no se me ha tenido que llamar al orden porque yo haya faltado al respeto debido. **Indirecta del padre  Cobos es una verdad desnuda, una mal llamada indirecta**, pero de ningún modo desvergüenza.

Pero ¿de dónde viene esta expresión?

Comment: es la primera vez que escucho este termino, 
Parece que el padre cobos es una figura que ha inspirado a los periodicos satiros... si es ficticio o real, pues se necesitaria mas investigacion, pero dada la naturaleza satira, pareceria que "la indirecta del padre cobos" no es mas que es sarcasm puro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He estado buscando y buscando, incluso pensando que el tal padre Cobos podría ser un personaje real (tal vez se refiriera a alguien real cuando la expresión era *indirecta de Cobos*), y lo único que he encontrado es un texto de mediados del siglo XIX, que dice [tal que así](https://books.google.es/books?id=LmqAAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA348&dq=%22padre%20cobos%22&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH2r_7rofYAhXIJuwKHR3JBggQ6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=%22padre%20cobos%22&f=false) (adapto el texto):

> Y explicaré por fin las indirectas del P. Cobos, aunque esta es de aquellas cosas que por sabidas se callan.
>         Había un padre guardián, no sé dónde, que como todos se tomaba unas jícaras de chocolate de padre y muy señor mío. Un amigote del fraile, aficionado al chocolate dio en visitarle a menudo y siempre a la hora en que se tomaba su paternidad el chocolate, el cual padre era tan fino que siempre mandaba hacer otra jícara para el amigo. Pero como el amigo estuvo abusando de la bondad del padre días y más días, hubo este de quejarse del amigo pegotón a lo cual contestó el lego que quedaba de su cuenta echarle una indirectilla para hacerle perder la costumbre. Convino el padre guardián, y notó que el amigo no volvía por el convento, y deseoso de saber la indirecta del lego, que se llamaba el P. Cobos, le preguntó al cabo de quince días, qué había dicho a su amigo que no había vuelto ni aun a visitarle. Una indirecta le contestó el padre Cobos: le dije, mire usted señor don Fulano, no sea usted bárbaro y váyase a su casa a tomar el chocolate; porque el padre guardián dice que es usted un glotón salvaje, y cada vez que usted viene le hace una gracia como si le rallaran las tripas.

Aunque el texto es de 1847, corresponde a una recopilación de relatos publicados en la revista [La Risa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Risa_(1843-1844)) (1843-1844). El relato original tampoco sé si es un relato que se contaba popularmente (con las variaciones que fueran, es posible dado que el autor dice que es algo sabido aunque no muy contado), o incluso si está basado en algún hecho real o figura real previa. Pero es posible que este relato fuera algo que se contara como chiste o anécdota por la época y que pudiera dar origen a la expresión "indirecta del padre Cobos", añadiendo el *padre* a la expresión anterior.

Con respecto a la expresión original, no he podido encontrar nada.